# Why are my headers bleeding?

Tags: jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I am trying to implement a [fixed column using datatables](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extensions/FixedColumns/examples/left_right_columns.html#). The example they give seems to look good. I've [implemented the same code in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yt4xmyh2/) but my headers bleed all over each other when I scroll right & left. How do I fix it?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        scrollY:        "300px",
        scrollX:        true,
        scrollCollapse: true,
        paging:         false
    } );

    new $.fn.dataTable.FixedColumns( table, {
        leftColumns: 1,
        rightColumns: 1
    } );
} );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you provided uses styles to hide the overlapping content which are not present in your jsfiddle. Specifically they add background colors to the columns that are fixed, so for instance:

```
column.stripe tbody tr.odd > .sorting_1 {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

See [dataTables.fixedColumns.css](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extensions/FixedColumns/css/dataTables.fixedColumns.css) and [jquery.dataTables.css](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/media/css/jquery.dataTables.css)

If you apply these styles to your fiddle everything looks ok: [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yt4xmyh2/1/).

Comment: When I set the width of "div.dataTables_wrapper" to 100% the fixed columns lose their bottom border. How do I correct that?http://jsfiddle.net/yt4xmyh2/3/

Comment: Which bottom border exactly? I don't think I see any difference here.

Comment: This is what I'm seeing (The bottom border of the table on each fixed column is missing): http://imgur.com/eW9NdhM

Comment: Ah ok, I see it now. I don't think that there is an easy fix... it may be best to remove the existing border from `.dataTables_wrapper.no-footer .dataTables_scrollBody` and add it back to the parent wrapper element. See my two extra style declarations all the way at the bottom here: http://jsfiddle.net/yt4xmyh2/4/

Comment: css kicks my a** everytime. Thanks for going above & beyond.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `background-color` to the required elements (usually td & th). Here's an updated fiddle (based on the one you provided): http://jsfiddle.net/cjqgmzb9/

By the way, if you use the CSS files provided by the plugin (see the CSS tab in the example you provided) the table should probably look exactly the same as the demo.

Comment: didn't see the additional css files. that was the part I was missing. thx!